# Embedding a native window inside a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, embedding

Does anyone know of a method or API that supports embedding a native window inside either a Java JFrame or JPanel?

I found this previous post:

[How do I run an external program inside a Java frame in netbeans in a platform independent manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524727/how-do-i-run-an-external-program-inside-a-java-frame-in-netbeans-in-a-platform-i)

I can get the window handle using:

http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/44064-getting-window-id-window-frame.html

and this works fine.

This article appears to suggest that it's possible, but does not illustrate how:

[Embed HWND (Window Handle) in a JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809713/embed-hwnd-window-handle-in-a-jpanel)

Comment: How does your question differ from the previous one you linked to? If it's the same question, you can put a bounty on it to get more attention to it. If you have enough reputation.

Comment: What do you mean by *"a native window"*?

Answer (score 0):

I can only repeat [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6525367/572834) given in another question: **This is not supported**.

Using Windows APIs, you can add a window into a `HWND` of `JFrame`, `Panel` (not `JPanel`!) or `Canvas`. Yet Java will never know you did it, it could break many assumptions inside AWT code.

Even when you write a native Win32 app, you can't embed an arbitrary window into your top-level window. If the window you want to embed is a top-level window, it may not play well when it's made a child window of another window because, again, the assumptions are now wrong, some messages are handled differently.

Comment: I see my original post was Jan 2014. Thank, but I couldn't wait 9 years.

Comment: @GrahamSeed It was still unanswered. I understand my answer doesn't bring much value to you. Yet it may be helpful to someone else researching the subject.